# WordPress change single image to SSL manually

Tags: images, ssl, https, migration, wordpress

I have (almost) succesfully migrated my WordPress Webpage from http:// to https://
Almost all pages are fully secure now (green lock), but for two pages, there is a mixed content warning:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'myUrL' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'URL-link-to-image'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.

What I have done so far:
I installed multiple plugings (Search & Replace, Better Search Replace ...) to try to "fix" this issue. All other images on my website are served properly via HTTPS. But two of them are not, and none of the plugins seem to be able to fix it.
I checked that the link http://myURl.com/myImage.jpeg also works for https://myURl.com/myImage.jpeg
I found the image in the DataBase under phpAdmin from the Provider I use (Strato).
But now I am unsure how to fix the content-serving. I am aware that directly meddling with the DB can have bad side-effects and I have 0 experience in doing so thus far.
Therefore, a well explained answer on how to tackle this issue is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem myself.
Problem was, that I used a page-builder (Elementor) and had to inform it about the SSL-Change, too.
To Do this: Elementor-->Tools-->replace URL

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that didn't use elementor, recommend using: the Really Simple SSL plugin to fix the issues. There's a paid versin too which isn't much and worth it if you have a good sized site to go through. https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/